# How to filter out sequences based on a given data using Python?

Tags: python, filter, filtering, bioinformatics, fasta

I would to filter out the sequences that I don't want based on a given file A.fasta. The original file contain all the sequences and fasta file is actually a file starts with sequence ID followed by its nucleotides that is represented by A, T, C, G. Can anyone help me?

**A.fasta**

```
>chr12:15747942-15747949
TGACATCA
>chr2:130918058-130918065
TGACCTCA
```

**Original.fasta**

```
>chr3:99679938-99679945
TGACGTAA
>chr9:135822160-135822167
TGACCTCA
>chr12:15747942-15747949
TGACATCA
>chr2:130918058-130918065
TGACCTCA
>chr2:38430457-38430464
TGACCTCA
>chr1:112381724-112381731
TGACATCA
```

**Expected output for C.fasta**

```
>chr3:99679938-99679945
TGACGTAA
>chr9:135822160-135822167
TGACCTCA
>chr2:38430457-38430464
TGACCTCA
>chr1:112381724-112381731
TGACATCA
```

**Code**

```
import sys
import warnings
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import BiopythonDeprecationWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',BiopythonDeprecationWarning)

fasta_file = sys.argv[1]  # Input fasta file
remove_file = sys.argv[2] # Input wanted file, one gene name per line
result_file = sys.argv[3] # Output fasta file

remove = set()
with open(remove_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            remove.add(line)

fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')

with open(result_file, "w") as f:
    for seq in fasta_sequences:
        nuc = seq.seq.tostring()
        if nuc not in remove and len(nuc) > 0:
            SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")
```

The code above will filter out repeated sequences but I would like to keep the repeated sequences if it does appear in the output

Comment: Don't filter out the `DeprecationWarning`! They are there for a reason: they  are there to tell you that the method `tostring()` is no longer used and will be removed in future versions of BioPython. Instead, use the more modern way of getting the string representation of a `Seq`object: instead of `nuc = seq.seq.tostring()`, write `nuc = str(seq.seq)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out look at [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page). Here is a solution using that:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

input_file = 'a.fasta'
merge_file = 'original.fasta'
output_file = 'results.fasta'
exclude = set()
fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(input_file),'fasta')
for fasta in fasta_sequences:
    exclude.add(fasta.id)

fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(merge_file),'fasta')
with open(output_file, 'w') as output_handle:
   for fasta in fasta_sequences:
        if fasta.id not in exclude:
            SeqIO.write([fasta], output_handle, "fasta")
```